# Executing source command befor building inside Docker Container (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: eclipse, docker, build

I want to build inside my docker container where the toolchain is installed.
This works fine when I start the container from CLI.
However I have to set the environment variables befor building.
This is done by a source command.

Now I like to build my project within eclipse.
I have chosen the 'Build inside Docker Image' Option and this also works so far.
But I find no solution to run the source command befor building.

Does anyone have a solution for this challenge?

Best Regards Jan